# Align image to left is not working. Tried text-align, float, etc

Tags: asp.net

Hi I am a beginner in ASP.Net. I have a web page that was working yesterday but now it's broken. I tried every solution that I found but it's not working. I'm sorry if there is a duplicate question but the solution didn't work for me.
Can you please help me.
My Code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap.min.js" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootbox.js" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootbox.min.js" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="jquery.js" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href ="jquery-1.11.3.min.js" rel="stylesheet" />


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="bootbox.min.js"></script>



    <title>


    </title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 100%;
        }


        .auto-style2 {
            height: 23px;
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            width: 252px;
        }
        .auto-style4 {
            height: 23px;
            width: 252px;
        }
        .auto-style5 {
            width: 381px;
        }
        .auto-style6 {
            height: 23px;
            width: 381px;
        }

        #ImageButton2{
             position: absolute;
             top: 0px;
             right: -1px; }
        .auto-style7 {
            width: 5px;
        }
        .auto-style8 {
            height: 23px;
            width: 5px;
        }
        #Image2{

              float:left;
               text-align: left; 

        }


        .left{
             float:left;

        }
        .test{
            float:left;
               text-align: left;

        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">

        function pLogin() {
            var result;
            bootbox.confirm("Do you have an existing account?", function (result) {
                if (result == true) {
                    window.location.href ="/login.aspx"
                }
                else
                 {}     
                });
                return false
            }





  </script>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <table class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style7">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style5">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style8">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="113px" ImageUrl="~/images/baby's logo.png" Width="407px" />
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style6">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style2"></td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" Height="111px" ImageUrl="~/images/ordernow.jpg" Width="135px" OnClientClick="javascript: return pLogin();" />

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
    <div>
        <hr />
    </div>
        <div>
            <p class="test">
              <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="500px" Style="float:left" ImageUrl="~/images/puto cake.jpg" Width="960px" />
            </p>
              </div>
         <div>



          </div>

        <div>
            <table class="nav-justified">
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style11">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style22">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold" ForeColor="Gray" Text="ORDER" ViewStateMode="Enabled" Width="100px"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style22">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold" ForeColor="Gray" Text="CUSTOMER SERVICE" ViewStateMode="Enabled" Width="239px"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style16">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold" ForeColor="Gray" Text="MY ACCOUNT" ViewStateMode="Enabled" Width="100px"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold" ForeColor="Gray" Text="CONNECT WITH BABY'S PUTO CAKE" ViewStateMode="Enabled" Width="317px"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style17"></td>
                    <td class="auto-style23">
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial Black" ForeColor="Black">Puto Cake</asp:HyperLink>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style23">
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial Black" ForeColor="Black">Contact Us</asp:HyperLink>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style20">
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial Black" ForeColor="Black">Create an Account</asp:HyperLink>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style21">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" Height="36px" ImageUrl="~/images/Facebook-128 (1).png" Width="44px" />
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" runat="server" Height="36px" ImageUrl="~/images/Twitter-Bird-128 (1).png" Width="44px" />
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton5" runat="server" Height="36px" ImageUrl="~/images/youtube_circle_color-512.png" Width="44px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style11">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style22">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style22">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style16">
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial Black" ForeColor="Black">Sign In</asp:HyperLink>
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style11">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style22">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style22">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style16">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style11">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style22">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style22">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style16">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>

    <div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />

    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

As I could see you didn't make you images like block elements (images are inline elements by default). Try try use `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` in your CSS classes and then use `text-align: left;`.

Also floated elements could behave wrong, because they "condensed" to the content even if you use a block level element. So also try to delete float rules from CSS classes or use `clear:left;`.

Comment: Hi, i tried it. the image was aligned to the left but it was not big. the width is 1024 but on the web page it is small.

Comment: @vaughnellisramos If you want to make images bigger you can use `width: 100%;  height 100%;` for them using different values for percentage if you want image smaller. Also you can use pixels instead of % like `width: 1024px;`